# What's the opposite word of "fluent"？

Tags: antonyms

I have searched and found "influent" and "unfluent", but I cannot find both of them in Merriam-Webster Dictionary and Collins. Or maybe there isn't a word adding a prefix to fluent that is the opposite at all? Which words can be alternates then?

Answer (score 2):

If you are speaking about fluency in a language, we would not likely say 'unfluent'.

Antonyms of words usually take something to a *negative* degree, rather than a reduced one. For example, 'unsafe' can actually mean something is *dangerous*, so you wouldn't use it to simply mean something didn't have the highest degree of safety.

Someone who has *some* grasp of a language might not be "fluent", but we would probably just say they were "not fluent" or, if they were progressing, "not *yet* fluent".

Other terms do exist for language spoken in a non-fluent way, such as "broken [language]", eg "they speak broken English". Sometimes the word "conversational" is used to describe a level of language competence at which you can hold a conversation with a native speaker, so you could say "I speak English but I am not yet conversational". Borrowing from the name of this site, you could also say "I'm learning English" to indicate you might not yet be fluent.

Comment: If someone's spoken command of a language is decidely not fluent, we can say that it is [halting](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/halting)

Comment: That should be `decidedly`

Comment: Actually, you use one possibility in your answer: **non-fluent**, which [we use with some frequency right here at ELL](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22non-fluent%22+site%3Aell.stackexchange.com).